# How to only apply certain rules to its text content and not its children

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In short, I have something like this:

```
<span class="className">
    Text text text <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
</span>

.className {
    font-style: italic;
    /* more */
}
```

I only wanted the "Text text text" to be italic, and [it works when I was using Bootstrap 3.0.3](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/q23ck/). However, when I [updated to Bootstrap 3.2.0](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/8ZtUh/), those rules are now also applying to the `button` in the `span`. That is not the behavior I wanted.

I am wondering if wrapping the text in another `span` is the only way to fix it. It would make the HTML even more complicated and I don't really want to do that. I can also explicitly override the `italic` rule:

```
.className > button {
    font-style: normal;
    /* more */
}
```

I don't think this code can be easily maintainable in the future thus I am not considering this one.

Is there any other way that only applies those rules only to the text content but not the button? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just .btn { font-style: normal; }?

Comment: @RwwL - The problem is `font-style` isn't the only style that is inheriting from the button's parent.

Answer (score 1):

Text will always inherit whatever style the parent (in this case .className) has. I think the best option would simply be to call something like:

```
button {
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Somewhere in the top, since you probably won't ever want an italic button on your page (honestly, I would expect this to be inside a reset somewhere, but I haven't chcked Bootstrap 3's new styles).

Comment: Well I guess I will have to manually reset all the styles then. Thanks.